# Firestore not asking to create indexes but query works

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am performing a complex query based on four fields, employee ID, year, month and day. The query works but I am not asked to create indexes. Is it fine if I leave it this way?

I have tried removing some fields, for example, querying only by the employee Id and the year of the attendance and it still works fine. I do not get any alert on the console.

`

```
function findAttendance(employee_id, date, callback) {
    db.collection('attendance')
        .where('employee.id', '==', employee_id)
        .where('date.day', '==', date.getDate())
        .where('date.month', '==', date.getMonth())
        .where('date.year', '==', date.getFullYear())
        .get().then((snapshot) => {
            callback(snapshot);
        })
}
```

`

I am expecting to get an error on the console asking me to create indexes, but I get none and the query works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using only equalities in your query, Firestore can do a [zig-zag-merge-join](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection) based on the auto-generated single-field indexes.

You *can* add an index on the field combination, which will typically speed up the query a bit, but it's not required.

To learn more about this, have a look at [How do queries work in Cloud Firestore?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&index=3&t=2s) in the [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ) series.